# How can i filter my start and end dates of one table using Date column from another table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables with the following details.

Table1 with startdate and enddate columns.

Table2 with qualifyingdate.

I want to get the final result of table1 based on the qualifyingdate in table2.

Example: Date is in yyyy-mm-dd format

table1:

```
         startdate   enddate
row1 : 2018-01-01    2018-03-31
row2 : 2018-02-01    2018-03-31
row3 : 2018-04-20    2018-06-30
row4 : 2017-07-01    2018-12-31
row5 : 2019-08-01    2020-11-30
```

table2:

```
   QualifyingDate   
row1 : 2018-03-01  
row2 : 2018-01-31  
row3 : 2018-04-20  
row4 : 2018-07-01  
row5 : 2018-08-01
```

final output from table1:

```
row1 : 2018-01-01  2018-03-31 (From table2, row1&row2 falls in between)
row2 : 2018-02-01  2018-03-31 (From table2, row1 falls in between)
row3 : 2018-04-20  2018-06-30 (From table2, row3 falls in between)
row4 : 2017-07-01  2018-12-31 (From table2, row1-row5 falls in between)
```

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where exists (select 1
              from table2 t2
              where t2.QualifyingDate between t1.startdate and t1.enddate
             );
```